# How to add drag & drop reorder feature to a plugin

Tags: wordpress, drag-and-drop, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm developing a wordpress website and I'm using [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin for custom post fields. I've add another plugin to add a [gallery option](https://wordpress.org/plugins/navz-photo-gallery/) to ACF and now I want to be able to reorder the gallery images by drag and dropping them. This specific field looks like this in the admin:

[image: the gallery plugin for ACF]

Does anybody know how to extend its functionality to enable drag & drop reorder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of great "sortable/drag-gable" plugins out there.

1. https://jqueryui.com/sortable/
2. https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/
3. https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

However, this is **just a front end** solution. I'd need to know a little more on how you plan to perform saving your galleries before I can suggest anything more.

Comment: In this gallery extension to ACF I don't need to go thru "create gallery", instead I just have to select the images I want and "insert media". Then it shows them in the admin like in the image in my question. Does this help?